# How to pass/read a PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile object?

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, with-statement

I have a PDF file that I convert to jpeg.
What I get is a list of images:

```
[<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FF46CDC10>,
 <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FE6651750>,
 <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FE6657450>,
 <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FE6657550>,
 <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FE6657650>,
 <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1700x2200 at 0x7F0FE6657790>]
```

I need to pass each of them to my AWS Textract pipeline to extract the tables and text.

The issue I can't pass these objects, they aren't files which I can open.
Please advise how to read/load such objects?

Comment: You can make them into Numpy arrays, if that helps `npArray = np.array(ONE_ITEM_FROM_YOUR_LIST)`

Comment: Or you can save one to disk as a JPEG with `ONE_ITEM_FROM_YOUR_LIST.save("image.jpg")`

Comment: @MarkSetchell is there any way to pass it to with open(image, "rb") ... ?
I would be happy to avoid saving it to files

Comment: @MarkSetchell tried with np.array, it doesn't work with with open(....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want a JPEG-encoded image in a memory buffer:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

# Encode your PIL Image as a JPEG without writing to disk
buffer = io.BytesIO()
YourImage.save(buffer, format='JPEG', quality=75)

# You probably want
desiredObject = buffer.getbuffer()
```

Comment: And where are my images here? I have a whole pipeline working with jpeg and png.
When I get a PDF file I need to be able to convert it to images and pass them to my pipeline.
The main function that calls aws textract is checking for the input file.

Comment: `YourImage` in my code corresonds to one item in your list of images.

Comment: And I can do the same with my png/jpeg files?

Comment: Sure. Just change to `format='PNG'` and remove `quality` parameter altogether.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had the hardest time working with this object